# Split directory path with another path

Tags: java, java-8

I read the directory path using system properties in java which will work both in windows and Linux based systems. Now I need to split this path with only a portion of the path to retrieve the rest. eg., `C:\Test1\Test2\Test3\Test4`

I need to split the above path with `C:\Test1\Test2` and retrieve `Test3\Test4`. 
When I get this as string and use `split` function that will give me error as illegal character because of `"\"` character. If I plan to escape this character with `"\\"`, this may not work in Linux box. Is there a way I can make this work both in Linux and Windows?

Comment: try `java.io.File.separator`.

Comment: Have you considered using interface [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below approach.

```
 //Windows
   String s = "C:\\Test1\\Test2\\Test3\\Test4";
   String[] output = s.split(("/".equals(File.separator))? File.separator : "\\\\" );
   //output: [C:, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4]

 //Linux:
   String linuxString = "/Test1/Test2/Test3/Test4";
   String[] linuxOutput = linuxString.split(("/".equals(File.separator))? File.separator : "\\\\" );
   //output: [, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4]
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: I have updated the answer, Please check. you can add a check the separator an based on the separator you can use the split.

Comment: You borrowed `File.separator` from my answer. Anyways, +1 for the implementation pain though! :)

Comment: @Sohail, this is going to return me a array or splits. Rather I want is a whole string as Test3/Test4. May be like the main path being split with C:/Test1/Test2 which I will be knowing. This final output may be like ["C:/Test1/Test2","Test3/Test4"]

Comment: @RaghavendraBankapur, if you know the first part then you can use somthing like this. 
      `String s = "C:\\Test1\\Test2\\Test3\\Test4";
       String[] output = new String[2];
       output[0] = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("Test2"));
       output[1] = s.substring(s.indexOf("Test2") + 6, s.length());
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output)); `

Comment: @Sohail this is more like indexing. If the values are going to be static it works fine. But when the values are going to be dynamic this may fail.
I could achieve it by

```String[] details= f.getAbsolutePath().substring(f.getAbsolutePath().length()-
                    (f.getAbsolutePath().length()-System.getProperty("path").length()));```

The above is going to give me 2 items in array. This worked both in Linux and windows.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `File.separator`. Use it to split your string.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator),

> The system-dependent default name-separator character, represented as a string for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern passed to `String.split` has the regular expression syntax, thus the `java.util.regex` package is the place to look for additional tools for dealing with them, like quoting a string to enforce literal matching.

So a solution only using system properties and string operations would look like

```
String path=System.getProperty("your.property"), sep=System.getProperty("file.separator");
for(String s: path.split(Pattern.quote(sep)))
    System.out.println(s);
```

However, there is no reason not to use the dedicated APIs:

```
Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("your.property"));
if(path.isAbsolute()) System.out.println(path.getRoot());
for(Path p: path)
    System.out.println(p);
```

Note that this also handles root paths correctly, i.e. on Windows, the root of a drive is like `C:\`, not `C:`, and on Linux, the root is `/`, not an empty string, and both cases are not handled correctly when just splitting at the separator chars.

Even before Java 7, there was an API that could handle this:

```
File path = new File(System.getProperty("your.property"));
for(File f = path; f != null; f = f.getParentFile())
    System.out.println(f.getName().isEmpty()? f.getPath(): f.getName());
```

though the code will iterate the elements in the opposite order.

---

Note, how simple your specific task of splitting at two levels above the path becomes with the dedicated API:

```
Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("your.property"));
Path first = path.getParent().getParent(), second = first.relativize(path);

System.out.println("first: "+first);
System.out.println("second: "+second);
```

Comment: this is going to give me 2nd portion of the path but split with individual parts. Ultimately I wanted was only 2 parts.

Comment: Did you read the entire answer, especially the last part? `first` and `second` are exactly two parts and if this operation doesn’t match your intention, you should edit your question to describe, what you actually want.

Comment: I did read your full answer. You solution will work if I know how deep I can penetrate with the parent. If this comes as a user input into my program then it will difficult. Keeping this option dynamic I commented that it may not work if my inputs are dynamic and not known. Anyways thank you for your answer.

Comment: That’s why I said, you should edit your question to describe, what you actually want. You received several answers telling you how to split at every separator. You keep telling that you don’t want that. You said, you want to split into two parts, which, given your example input, would be split at a certain depth. If that’s not the criteria, you should specify the actual criteria. On the other hand, if the `first` part is known, like hinted in one of your comments, just ignore the `.getParent().getParent()` operation and focus on the `second = first.relativize(path)` solution to get the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use separator when you are building a file path.

Use java.io.File.separator